# UIImageView consumes memory when hidden? (iOS)

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, uiimageview

Does UIImageView requires memory when it is hidden?
Same question for alpha=0.0

I work a lot with hidden images, and I wonder if those still consume memory.

More specifically I would like to know that for tableview.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course **if it has an image loaded into the view**, it does, because `UIImageView` is simply a `UIView` that has a `UIImage` @property with the `retain` attribute so it retains the image.

The fact that the view is visible or not does not change anything of course, and hopefully because otherwise iOS couldn't load the `UIImage` again if you set the `UIImageView` visible again (once the `image` property is affected to the `UIImageView`, the `UIImageView` can't know the source of the image, was it loaded from a file, an URL, generated programatically, ...?), and even if it did know it would be a pain to reload it (could take some time to load and decode)

If you don't use an `UIImageView`'s image, at least set its `image` property to `nil` to hide it (and reload/reaffect the image again yourself if you need to redisplay it, but if it is used in a `UITableView` because of the recycling/reuse mechanism of the `UITableViewCells` it will probably never be the same image to set anyway)